# Splash screen with no scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Days ago I made a simple splash screen that is currently fixed and sets a cookie when the user clicks the button (to never appear again).

Basically, It is just a div that appears in front of the main content of the page.

My problem is that even though the splash screen uses all the width and height, the scrollbar keeps appearing. I did not care about this at the first time, as it was `position:fixed`'d and the content was always there, impossible to move with scroll up or down.

Today I saw that on mobiles, when you scroll, sometimes you can see the content behind the splash screen.

So the main problem is the scroll bar. Therefore I decided to hide the scroll bar at all costs.
But `overflow:hidden` does not work.
It does not work also if I put `position: relative` to the parent of the splash.

How can I disable the scroll? Is there anyway I can do it with CSS? Should I use javascript to solve the problem?

Here is a fiddle of my splash and my home page:
http://jsfiddle.net/tomas2387/G8M4D/

As you can see, the splash screen is in front, but the scrolling is there, even though I use `overflow:hidden`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding:

```
html,body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Works for me**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8M4D/1/)

Alternatively- depending what you're specifically after, you may want to add:

```
html,body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Then wrap everything after the `modal--mobile-splashpage` part within another element and hide this when the splash is being shown. You can then toggle the two (splash and content) as you see fit. [See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/G8M4D/5/)

Answer (score 2):

```
html,body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And when you hide splash screen just use jquery to get back scroll

```
$('html,body').css('overflow','auto');
```

Comment: true, because if I don't do that my main page will have no scroll. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
body {
     overflow-y: scroll;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
}
```